# how to pass by reference a struct for binary search C++

Tags: c++, struct, binary, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct student
{
    char name[30];
    char surname[50];
    int AM;
    int age;
}st;

int binsearch(st *s, int left, int right, int x) // the program crashes when i try to do the search                     
{
    while (left <= right)
    {
        int middle = (left +right) / 2;
        if (s[middle].AM == x)
            return middle;
        else if (x > s[middle].AM)
            left = middle + 1;
        else
            right = middle - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main ()
{
    int ap,flag=1,n,i=0;

    st *s;
    while(ap != 0)
    {
       cout << "\n1. Create array" << endl;
       cout << "2. Print the array" << endl;
       cout << "3. Binary Search " << endl;
       cout << "0. Exit" << endl;
       cout << "Please give an answer ";
       cin >> ap;

       if (ap == 1)
       {

          ifstream file1("students.txt");
          if (!file1)
          {
          cout << "Unable to open file for reading.\n";
          return(1);
          }
          file1 >> n;
          s = new st[n];
          while (i < n)
          {
             file1 >> s[i].name  >> s[i].surname >> s[i].AM >> s[i].age;
             i++;
          }
          flag = 2;

       }
       if (ap == 2 && flag == 2)
       {
          for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
              cout << s[i].name << " "  << s[i].surname << " " << s[i].AM << " " << s[i].age << " " << endl;
          }
       }
       if (ap == 3 && flag == 2)
       {
           int x, i, left = s[0].AM, right = s[n].AM, middle; // the error is somewhere here 

           cout << "Give the AM to search  "; // AM is a single number something like an ID number
           cin >> x;c 
           middle = binsearch(s, left, right, x);
           if(middle != -1)
           {
               cout << "We have found the student !" << endl;
           }
           else
           {
               cout << "We didn't find the student  %d" << x << endl;
           }

       }
    };
    delete[] s;
    return 0;
}
```

I think i'm passing the wrong type in the binary search function.
I have tried turning int right and int left to st which is the `struct student` in the function 
I have no clue what to do next.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: because bin search is algorithm with several "off by ones", easiest way is to check some already implemented one. this is what I usually copy from:  
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/bsearch.c  
(by posting this, I do not say "copy the code", check it line by line and just use it just to avoid "off by one" errors.

Comment: Your code is hardly C++. Get rid of those pointers, use `std::string` and forget about the `typedef struct` trick from C.

Comment: You seem to be writing [tag:C] code in [tag:C++] headers. Thats why you aren't using pointers instead of references. I would have loved to explain this in an answer but i need to thoroughly change your code for the same

Comment: This isn't C++ !!!!!!! Plus pass-by-reference is not by pointers in C++ unlike in C. C++ has a different entity called reference. Your code needs hell lot of modifications !!!

Comment: Which pass-by-reference are u talking abt ? Be clear

Comment: Signature to pass by reference is `int binsearch(const student& s, int left, int right, int x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid index of s should be from 0 to n-1. So "right = s[n].AM" is trying to access beyond the end of your allocated memory.

Comment: How can you answer this question when it asks how to pass by reference and your changes do not update the code so that it passes by reference? -1

Answer (score 0):

In the line which you've commented, (int x, i, left = s[0].AM, right = s[n].AM, middle;) it should be s[n-1].AM because an array of size n has index only from 0 to n-1.

Comment: How can you answer this question when it asks how to pass by reference and your changes do not update the code so that it passes by reference? -1

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int x, i, left = s[0].AM, right = s[n].AM, middle; // the error is somewhere here
> ```

couple of changes here:

- no need to declare variable i again, if you need that variable for some purpose, consider changing its name.
- s[n] should be s[n-1]

Comment: How can you answer this question when it asks how to pass by reference and your changes do not update the code so that it passes by reference? -1